# Receiver app code testing

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am currently looking for the best way to test my receiver app code. I would like to know if there is a way to have a non-production version of the receiver app code running, which is not visible to my users, so that I can test new functionalities without possibly breaking others that are currently live and in production. So far I have been doing trial and error with small snippets, but this is far from optimal.

My final goal is to be able to create different GIT branches of my code, which I can test on my Chromecast that is not visible to the public.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create another app id to be used for testing/development; as long as you do not publish that app id, no other device but your registered devices can see that app.